# code not getting highlighted how to fix it

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How can I fix my dart code by not highlighting my code syntax even after uninstalling and reinstalling the flutter, dart extension on vs code and  reinstalling the flutter sdk?

I uninstalled and reinstalled both the dart and flutter extension and the flutter sdk and my code was still not getting highlighted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Please also include the version of your Dart extension and what Dart and Flutter SDK you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the VS Code theme you're using.

Go to
Setting Icon >Themes > Color Theme > Select Dark+

[image]

Normal Dark theme only shows limited colours so try Dark+ .